# How can I assign a function result to a name in the WITH clause of a SELECT?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle19c, with-clause

How can I assign a function result to a name in the WITH clause?

Tried:

```sql
with
    has_perm as ( has_perm(:user) )
select * from my_table where has_perm = 'Y'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "assign a function result to a name in the WITH clause". Do you mean define an inline function, e.g. `with function has_perm(params) return number`, like [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
with has_perm as (
      select has_perm(:user) as has_perm
      from dual
     )
select *
from my_table
where 'Y' = (select has_perm from has_perm);
```

Why not just write this without a CTE?

```
select *
from my_table
where has_perm(:user) = 'Y';
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, though that there would be a better syntax to do this.
Answering your question, because `has_perm` has many parameters in my case.